# Network Discovery wont work over OpenVswitch VXLANs tunnels

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, openvswitch, vxlan

I have working Openvswitch VXLANs, Recently i noticed Network Discovery wont work over VXLAN tunnels across different Hypervisors. Virtual machines can use all file sharing etc if accessed through IP addresses But not visible automatically under network discovery

For example multiple Virtual machines on different Hypervisors can access each other over VXLAN tunnels,  But they wont appear in Network Discovery of each other.

Virtual machines on same Hypervisor using same Vxlan bridge can Discover each other just fine.

Is this a real issue or something i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Open vSwitch [VXLAN lacks multicast support](https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/faq/vxlan/), which most such network discovery protocols require.

> Open vSwitch currently supports the framing format for packets on the wire. There is currently no support for the multicast aspects of VXLAN. To get around the lack of multicast support, it is possible to pre-provision MAC to IP address mappings either manually or from a controller.

I really wouldn't expect this workaround to help with service discovery though.